# Edit the user data by it's Id on specific index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to edit the user data by its specific MongoDB, When I click on it, it opens a new modal popup and below that there is a update button, after clicking it I want the user data situated on the edit index line would change.
Below is my code:

```
function tableShowUser() {
  document.getElementById("tbod").innerText = "";
  axios
    .get("")
    .then((response) => {
      dataUsers = response.data;
      //console.log(dataUsers);
      if (dataUsers.length === 0) {
        alert("Please Create a User first!!");
      } else {
        dataUsers.map((item, index) => {
          let iddata = item;
          //console.log(iddata._id);
         // console.log(iddata, index);
          var id = item._id
         // console.log(id);

          let trUsers = document.createElement("tr");
          let td1 = document.createElement("td");
          td1.id = `${item._id}_userName`
          
          
          let td2 = document.createElement("td");
          let td3 = document.createElement("td");
          let td4 = document.createElement("td");
          let td5 = document.createElement("td");
          let td6 = document.createElement('td');

          var btn1edit = document.createElement("button");
          btn1edit.textContent = "EDIT";

          btn1edit.addEventListener("click", () => {
            editwindow();
          });

          document.querySelector(".update").addEventListener("click", () => {
            upDATE(`${item._id}_userName`);
          });

          var btn2delete = document.createElement("button");
          btn2delete.textContent = "DELETE";

          btn2delete.onclick = function () {
            DELETE(iddata._id);
          };

          console.log(td1);
  
          td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
          td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.email));
          td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.address));
          td4.appendChild(btn1edit);
          td5.appendChild(btn2delete);
          td6.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item._id));

          trUsers.appendChild(td1);
          trUsers.appendChild(td2);
          trUsers.appendChild(td3);
          trUsers.appendChild(td4);
          trUsers.appendChild(td5);
          trUsers.appendChild(td6)
          document.getElementById("tbod").appendChild(trUsers);
        })
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}



function upDATE(editid) {
  let name = document.getElementById("upName").value;
  let email = document.getElementById("upEmail").value;
  let address = document.getElementById("upAddress").value;
  if (name == "" && email == "" && address == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Something in USER input field(s)!!");
  } else {
    axios
      .put(`${editid}`, {
        name,
        email,
        address, //if value pairs have same name then we can write it like this
      })
      .then((response) => {
        alert("User Updated Successfully");
        console.log(response.data);
        tableShowUser()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("upName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("upEmail").value = "";
    document.getElementById("upAddress").value = "";
  },2000)
  cLose();
}
```

when I call `upDATE()` function it should update the specific index, but all it is doing is given me undefined or updating all the users with the same edit, as they are in the loop.
Please suggest me something, I really need something even a hint would be good.
Thank you
Feel free to edit the question

Answer (score 0):

.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {

```
data = response;
console.log(data.pop());
```

})

Comment: doesn't it only returns the last user ? but I there is like random numbers of users, and what if I want the 2nd or the 5th one ? does it work?